# How to develop "Form Builder" web part?

Tags: web-part, form

I want a **Form Builder** web part. This web part would create basic forms dynamically on the fly by drag-and-drop controls. These forms would send the form values as an email and/or store information in a custom list. Has anyone developed something similar in .NET?

This is an example of what exactly I am talking about: http://jotform.com !!!

I would appreciate all inputs to advise how to implement such a thing as a web part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having a look at [iTechnology Forms Accelerator](http://www.myitechnology.com/itfa.aspx). A colleague of mine found this and it's free (however I don't know what the support story is). I haven't used it but it looks like it will meet your needs without custom development.

Answer (score 2):

Just creating a list and adding the appropriate columns to it is a form builder. SharePoint generates great forms right out of the box.  If you want to send the form values somewhere, then you can use simple workflows to send out the emails, copy some or all values to other lists, etc.  In other words, are you trying to recreate the wheel?

Comment: Also Alex, any of the forms associated with lists can be easily customised using SharePoint Designer, and there is nothing stopping you adding jQuery/javascript to these custom forms to add more rich client functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Check [SharePoint Forms Designer](http://spform.com/), it fits all your requirements, easy to use, drag and drop rich interface, works right in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at infopath

Comment: Thanks Jaap Vossers for writing to me, but actually I want a very basic web part that builds up very basic forms. Not at all InfoPath level !!!